# converting class into interface

Tags: java, android

please help me about that how i can convert my class into interface so other classes can use main menu . or let me know if there is easy way to call the same  menu in the main class except extends bcz there are classes which already are extending other classes. here is the sample code

```
package com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ControlMenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:     
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
            break;
            case R.id.services:     
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Test.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
              break;
            case R.id.Quit: 

                finish();



                break;
            default:    
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

i want to call these menus into other classes (one of them are listed below) so that option menu is available on every activity without using extends.

```
public class Test extends ListActivity  {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/fetch.php");

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("name"));
                map.put("password", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("password"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

now i am following this way

```
package com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MenuHandler extends Activity{
    private Activity activity;

    public MenuHandler(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = activity.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:     
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
              startActivity(intent);
        break;
        case R.id.services:     
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Test.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
          break;
        case R.id.Quit: 

            finish();



            break;
        default:    
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}
and Test class is

```
package com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test extends ListActivity  {
    private MenuHandler menuHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        menuHandler = new MenuHandler(this);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/fetch.php");

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("name"));
                map.put("password", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("password"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return menuHandler.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return menuHandler.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

menu are perfectly appearing on the screen but when i am clicking on any menu it "Force to stop" pops up

Now i am able to get logat errors  Here they are 
[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible without extends. I don't really see why you would not want to extend it?

Comment: what would be the case for this public class Test extends ListActivity how i will extend control menu over here , this is the reason i am finding other ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create a special class to handle menu creation and events and delegate everythng to it. The code will look like this:

```
public class MenuHandler {
    private Activity activity;

    public MenuHandler(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = activity.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //Handle events here
    }
}
```

Then when you need to have a menu in your `Activity`, you create `MenuHandler` and delegate method calls to it:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MenuHandler menuHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        menuHandler = new MenuHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return menuHandler.onCreateOprionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return menuHandler.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Certainly, there's absolutely no difference.

Comment: sorry about this question , in the  Test class i need to call the code that you have stated in the Myactivity even it is extending from list activity

Comment: Exactly. In your case Test class will be MyActivity in my code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Malcolm . I will try to implement this and if some problem occur i will disturb u a bit :)

Comment: Hello Malcolm. please help me a bit more . i have update the program as u told but i am facing the problem that menu are appreaing perfectly but when i click anyone of the it force to stop pops up

Comment: You should look up in DDMS which exception is thrown and on which line, that should tell us what's happening.

Comment: yeh i have posted that question too . there is nothing in logcat and DDMS and when i tried to run on emulator this screen show up as i have put it over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843134/logcat-is-empty-and-show-searching-screen

Answer (score 1):

An interface does not have an implementation, so I don't think that will do what you want.

What you can do is make an activity that extends your `ControlMenu`. It will be an Activity (because controlmenu itself extends activity), and it will be able to use the code you have provided here. It will look something like

```
public class yourActivity extends ControlMenu{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //oncreate of controlmenu
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        ListView lv = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlistview, ll, false);
        ll.addView(lv);
        lv.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(this)); 
    }
}
```

and you'll have an adapter that goes like (quick mock-up)

```
public abstract class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   final public int getCount() {}
   final public Object getItem(int position) {}
   final public long getItemId(int position) {}
   final public void onItemClick() {}
```

}

Comment: what would be the case for this public class Test extends ListActivity  how i will extend control menu over here , this is the reason i am finding other ways

Comment: You could make an adapter, and use that to fill a List from an Activity?

Comment: i have updated my question in detail with code of next class where i want to call(actually i dont want to rewrite the menus again) . pleaseee check it out . if your solution work over there . let me know so i can implement

Comment: Now i am getting logcat please check it out the updated question