# repetition in the menu

Tags: java, android

Please help me out regarding repeating the menu.

First class:

```
public class A extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:     
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
            break;
            case R.id.services:     
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Test.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
              break;
            case R.id.Quit: 

                finish();



                break;
            default:    
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

second class

```
public class Test extends ListActivity  {


            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               over here i will be fetching the list from the server 
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.settings:     
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
                          startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                    case R.id.services:     
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Test.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                      break;
                    case R.id.Quit: 

                        finish();



                        break;
                    default:    
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I have tried [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841283/converting-class-into-interface) but it was not working.

previous logcat

```
04-30 23:32:09.906: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
04-30 23:32:09.906: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
04-30 23:32:09.906: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
04-30 23:32:09.906: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
04-30 23:32:26.345: ERROR/MemoryHeapBase(65): error opening /dev/pmem: No such file or directory
04-30 23:32:26.345: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(65): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
04-30 23:32:26.475: ERROR/libEGL(65): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
04-30 23:32:27.234: ERROR/libEGL(76): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
04-30 23:32:31.694: ERROR/BatteryService(65): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/usb/online'
04-30 23:32:31.694: ERROR/BatteryService(65): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_vol'
04-30 23:32:31.694: ERROR/BatteryService(65): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_temp'
04-30 23:32:32.445: ERROR/EventHub(65): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
04-30 23:32:32.445: ERROR/EventHub(65): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
04-30 23:32:33.116: ERROR/System(65): Failure starting core service
04-30 23:32:33.116: ERROR/System(65): java.lang.SecurityException
04-30 23:32:33.116: ERROR/System(65):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
04-30 23:32:33.116: ERROR/System(65):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
04-30 23:32:33.116: ERROR/System(65):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
04-30 23:32:33.116: ERROR/System(65):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:162)
04-30 23:32:33.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(65): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
04-30 23:32:35.514: ERROR/LockPatternKeyguardView(65): Failed to bind to GLS while checking for account
04-30 23:32:43.175: ERROR/ActivityThread(109): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
04-30 23:32:43.205: ERROR/ActivityThread(109): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
04-30 23:32:49.344: ERROR/ApplicationContext(65): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/wallpaper-hints.xml
04-30 23:32:50.144: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
04-30 23:32:52.407: ERROR/ActivityThread(106): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
04-30 23:32:55.918: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
04-30 23:32:55.949: ERROR/MediaPlayer(65): Unable to to create media player
04-30 23:32:56.969: ERROR/ActivityThread(106): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
04-30 23:32:57.237: ERROR/ActivityThread(106): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
04-30 23:33:18.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:95)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:689)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onInvalidated(AdapterView.java:813)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyInvalidated(DataSetObservable.java:43)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(BaseAdapter.java:54)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter$SimpleFilter.publishResults(SimpleAdapter.java:391)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
04-30 23:33:18.848: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 23:33:29.837: ERROR/ActivityThread(109): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109): Error recording stats
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:476)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.net.GoogleHttpClient.executeWithoutRewriting(GoogleHttpClient.java:241)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.net.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:278)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.net.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:348)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch.SuggestionProvider.sendGenieSearchRequest(SuggestionProvider.java:587)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch.SuggestionProvider.querySearchSuggestions(SuggestionProvider.java:316)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch.SuggestionProvider.query(SuggestionProvider.java:262)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SearchableSuggestionSource.getSuggestions(SearchableSuggestionSource.java:268)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SearchableSuggestionSource.getCursor(SearchableSuggestionSource.java:216)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SearchableSuggestionSource.getSuggestions(SearchableSuggestionSource.java:166)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.AbstractSuggestionSource$1.call(AbstractSuggestionSource.java:75)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.AbstractSuggestionSource$1.call(AbstractSuggestionSource.java:68)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.QueryMultiplexer$SuggestionRequest.run(QueryMultiplexer.java:172)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.PerTagExecutor$Limiter$1.run(PerTagExecutor.java:106)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
04-30 23:33:29.849: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider$SuggestionThread.run(SuggestionProvider.java:102)
04-30 23:33:29.998: ERROR/ActivityThread(109): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109): Error recording stats
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:476)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.net.GoogleHttpClient.executeWithoutRewriting(GoogleHttpClient.java:241)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.net.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:278)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.net.GoogleHttpClient.execute(GoogleHttpClient.java:348)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch.SuggestionProvider.sendGenieSearchRequest(SuggestionProvider.java:587)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch.SuggestionProvider.querySearchSuggestions(SuggestionProvider.java:316)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.google.android.providers.enhancedgooglesearch.SuggestionProvider.query(SuggestionProvider.java:262)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:129)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:152)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SearchableSuggestionSource.getSuggestions(SearchableSuggestionSource.java:268)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SearchableSuggestionSource.getCursor(SearchableSuggestionSource.java:216)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SearchableSuggestionSource.getSuggestions(SearchableSuggestionSource.java:166)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.AbstractSuggestionSource$1.call(AbstractSuggestionSource.java:75)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.AbstractSuggestionSource$1.call(AbstractSuggestionSource.java:68)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.QueryMultiplexer$SuggestionRequest.run(QueryMultiplexer.java:172)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.PerTagExecutor$Limiter$1.run(PerTagExecutor.java:106)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
04-30 23:33:30.047: ERROR/GoogleHttpClient(109):     at com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider$SuggestionThread.run(SuggestionProvider.java:102)
```

instead of emulator when i tried to run on the android i got the following logcat [image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that there is some issue with reusing the same menu in multiple activities? You have posted a lot of code, and not very much explanation of what you are trying to do, or what bugs you're experiencing. Could you (if you can) elaborate on your question and restrict the code to what is relevant to your issue? Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to short down the test class . The thing is that i want to call the menu of the first class in the second class but i cant do it because its already extending listactivty. so i have to rewrite it and there is repetition , so i was wondering is there any way to get rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried only the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method of the code provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841283/converting-class-into-interface) you have mentioned and it works.

From the code (still from the link, in the `MenuHandler.java`)

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:     
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
              startActivity(intent);
        break;
        case R.id.services:     
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Test.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
          break;
        case R.id.Quit:
```

Make sure you call the new activity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ShowSettings.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Same inside the `case R.id.services`

Comment: yeh i am calling in this way , this function is working well but the thing i that if want to run code from the previous link it tells me force to close

Comment: well, in the previous link, you use `startActivity` instead of `activity.startActivity`. So you should update with the code you have tried last, and put the log from logcat.

Comment: oh sorry, i havent noticed . let me try in this way

Comment: i have changed it with activity.startActivity and now getting the logcat at stated above

Comment: Hum i dont see any references to your activities name (`Test`, `ShowSettings`). Maybe the problem is somewhereelse and the above code works fine

Comment: What s happenning when you click the "Menu" button? Does it crash or show you some submenu or start an activity?

Comment: i have updated with the picture of logat which i am getting from running on android instead of emulator . when i click on menu button on phone the menu pops up but when i click any button of menu it crashes and exit from the app . can i attach my code if u have some time

Comment: It seems that the line `Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ShowSettings.class);` returns null.

Comment: Make sure `ShowSettings` activity is declared in the manifest. And try to run in DEBUG mode and put breakpoints at the `Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ShowSettings.class);` line

Comment: showsettings and other activities are decleared in the manifest file . and i no  idea how to run in dubug mode although i have tried with Debug as android application and was getting the same error logcat except with one new thing "Failed Binder Transaction  " . I have taken a lot of time from you . its ok i will manage with repetition :) .in future if u find some tutorial related to this approach plz let me know . Thanks for your precious time .